# here::here function is inconsistent in finding the working directory path

Tags: r, file

I'm using R and the here package to save plots into a file in the current working directory like this:

```
save(plot1,
     file = here::here("out2.rda"))
```

My working directory and the source file location of the project is a sub-folder in my Google Drive folder. My working directory is that subfolder, I checked this by running `setwd()` with the appropriate file path.

However, sometimes the `here::here("out2.rda")` doesn't save to that folder but instead saves to my Documents folder on my PC. Other times it works fine and saves to the desired folder in my Google Drive. I can not figure out why it works only sometimes.

**How can I make sure it works all the time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`here::here()` determines the working directory / project root at [package load time](https://here.r-lib.org/reference/here.html). Thus `setwd()` only influences the project root as determined by `here::here()` if it is called before either `library(here)` or any function from the package. Do you have a `library(here)` call in your script? Is it possible that you are starting the R sessions from different places at times (either through command line or RStudio)? The latter will influence the R session's working directory.

I recommend having an .Rproj file at the root of your project (the subdirectory of the Google Drive folder in your case). If you work in Rstudio, you can open the .Rproj file directly which will set the correct working directory. The here package will also use .Rproj files to locate the current working directory, provided you started the R session from the folder containing the project file or a subfolder of it.

I can also recommend [this blog post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/) that explains project-oriented workflows well.